# Calculate total amount PGSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

**query which calculates the total amount in dollars of stolen goods for each month for restricted and neutral items.**

I have 2 tables

*first*

```
  | UPC | item | in_stock | price | ship_day   | class |
1 | 101 | 'generator' | 16 | 5999 | '12-1-2065'| 'restricted'
2 | 102 | 'blank tape' | 30 | 3000 | '12-1-2065'| 'neutral'
```

*second*

```
   | UPC | unit_stolen |
1 | 101 | 4 |
1 | 401 | 2 |
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, this is basically a `join` and `group by`:

```
select date_trunc('mon', f.ship_day) as yyyymm,
       sum(f.price * s.unit_stolen) filter (where f.class = 'restricted'),
       sum(f.price * s.unit_stolen) filter (where f.class = 'neutral')
from first f join
     second s
     on f.upc = s.upc
group by date_trunc('mon', f.ship_day)
```

Comment: @TomerAvraham . . . This does sum the total amount -- times the quantity.